# Table of convolutes

Tags: map, convolution, iteration

### Inputs

Start with a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and a vector-valued function  $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

### Output

Given some $k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, what are elegant ways to produce the table of convolutes?

```
{x, f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), ..., f^{k}(x)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $ k = 6 $,

```
NestList[f, x, 6]
```

> ```
> {x, f[x], f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]], f[f[f[f[x]]]], f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]}
> ```